# How to color the status bar icons in Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notification-bar, notification-icons

Since the introduction of Android Lollipop, Google made all status-bar icons white. Disregarding the app own icon colors. This is a horrible design blunder and I'm looking for ways to hack around this. The closest I could get was to [reduce the TargetSdkVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color) to below 21, but this is a no go for me. Any better suggestions?